# Question about Japanese text (image)

Tags: meaning

Hope you are fine. Maybe you can help me with my problem. Would you mind letting me know what the text on the shirt translates or what it means in english please? (see attachment)

Thank you so much!

James Galea[image]

Answer (score 1):

It says Kendo (剣道). It's a Japanese martial art which evolved from swordsmanship - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendo).